# Has DFT helped in development of better solar materials?

Tags: density-functional-theory, education, materials-engineering, solar-cells

I would like to pursue a Masters degree in Materials Science and more focused towards solar materials to make it more efficient and reducing the [energy payback time](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/energy-payback-time).
I had taken this [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/solar-cells) and was pretty sure that material science has a humongous role for a solar future.

I just wanted to know how computational material science and in turn DFT, has played a role in developing better solar materials.
In specific Thin-film solar materials and CIGS solar cells!

Comment: @Nike Dattani Is it possible to have a chat room only for Solar materials?

Comment: +1 Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/24/5. Perhaps try to make your question more unique so that no one close votes as a duplicate. As for the chat room, you are welcome to make one! Click on "site rooms" in the LAMMPS one, then make one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has materials modeling made any specific contribution to the success of perovskite solar cells, or has it only been experimental?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/24/has-materials-modeling-made-any-specific-contribution-to-the-success-of-perovski)

Comment: I think that the question can be improved and not be considered a duplicate, since the @SaiSmaranSBPES1201701189PES does not specifically ask about perovskites. It would be interesting to see what else folks explore!

Comment: @CodyAldaz No, I have specifically mentioned TF solar materials & CIGS solar cells! Perovskites are different.

Answer (score 6):

To make a start in answering this question, [here](https://doi.org/10.1038/natrevmats.2015.4) is a review on "Computational predictions of energy materials using DFT" by Jain et al. (2016).

The bar for inclusion was:

> examples where theoretical prediction has led to the experimental discovery of a new material or exposed an important technological facet of a known material.

Table 1 contains a couple of examples from the photovoltaics field (although not the specific subfields mentioned in the question):

> - 2007 PCDTBT, Candidate copolymer donor material with high power conversion efficiency for bulk-heterojunction organic photovoltaic solar cells
> - 2014 Organic dyes, New class of organic dyes for dye‐sensitized solar cells
> - 2013–2015, Ba2BiTaO6, p-Type transparent conducting oxide that utilizes alignment between Bi 6s and O 2p states
> - 2014, TaIrGe, Unconventional p-type half-Heusler transparent conducting oxide composed of all heavy metal atoms

By now, publishing an update of this table would probably be worthwhile.